# Is it good practice to Store Age of a Person in Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I need to search through thousands of records of type 'Person' and fetch the ones, say: Age between 25 and 30. So is it a good practice if I store the age at the write time itself and run a scheduler to update the age on every persons bday. A scheduler that runs everday for all the person having birthday that day. I know this is wrong for relational database. Could someone experienced in GAE/J guide me on this.

Comment: Surely you can store the DOB and calculate it when you query the data. Why on earth would you want to add complexity?

Answer (score 0):

My proposal might be a bit off topic, but could make your job much simpler.

Having non-normalized DB schema might make sense for your use case. However I believe you can achieve this without any background job.

I'd store dates as integers in the DB:

- for example for 2011-01-01 you would store: 20110101
- ...

afterwards you'd do between like this:

- let's say today is 20130810 AND you search for 1 year old people:

  - so you'd end up with something like: BETWEEN (20110811, 20120810)

The problem is that you'd do between each time you search (so no database index would be probably involved), but if you search for age intervals anyway, that should not hurt as your queries would skip indexes anyway